# C++ Get virtual function table without the instance of the object

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, rtti

**Question:** Is there a way to retrieve a VF Table pointer from the type of the object via some templates/rtti hacks/win32, without creating an actual instance of the object? If possible, I'd like to avoid parsing PDB, Module, I'd like to find the VF table at runtime.

It's easy to retrieve VF table when you have the instance of the object already, so currently I have the type, I just create dummy instance of the type and then retrieve the pointer, but not all my types have default constructor, so I cannot always use this solution.

I'm working on a **C++ Win32** project, no need for multiplatform solution.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: I implemented runtime DLL reload, so when I have classes created from a DLL and this DLL is unloaded, recompiled and then loaded, the VF table pointers are invalid, because they are pointing to a code that was unloaded. To fix this, I just create the dummy class of the object type from the newly loaded DLL, get it's VF table pointer and assign it to the broken object. This system works perfectly for my purposes, but it's annoying, that every class needs to be default constructible. I checked the RCC++ solution, but seems they have the same limitation, all classes must be default constructible.

Comment: *get it's VF table pointer and assign it to the broken object.* - if dll create object which have pointers to this dll (references)- it must not be unloaded until all this objects not destroyed.

Comment: From standard point of view, this would be undefined behavior (or maybe compiler specific). What you are doing is very dangerous because you need to understand how your compiler works beyond what is probably officially documented and nothing would prevent anyone to make incompatible changes to the classes and by the way how could you even know the size of the v-table?

Comment: I'm aware of how dangerous it is. But for my needs it's ok, I just want to know how to retrieve VF table without creating an object instance.

Comment: @gamer9xxx you can't. You need to change your code so the DLL is not unloaded while active objects are referring to it. That is the only safe (and sane) option.

Comment: Could you add a custom constructor, rather than a default constructor, perhaps with custom operator new, to all your classes, such that the custom constructor does the minimum possible work?
I worry that if you call default constructors the chance of one of the constructors calling a virtual method before you get to do fixup is still quite high?